# In redux best practice, should the initial state nil value be set to undefined or null?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, flux

**Which way is best practice：**

When we use null as nil value:

Pros:

`null` has better semantics, the variable is indeed assigned, not `undefined`.

Cons:

Where we need to use it, we need to do the conversion of the data, which is tedious. Especially in the case of components and api calls, which are optional parameters.

```js
// store
const initState = {
  user: User | null
}

// Child component
type ComponentProps = {
  user?: User
}
const Component: FC<ComponentProps> = ...

// Parent component
const {user} = store
<Component user={user !== null ? user : undefined}>

// Update state when we need nil value
setUser(null)

// Api call
api.getSomething({ user: store.user !== null ? store.user : undefined })
```

When we use undefined

Pros:

Where it is used, it will be very clear.

Cons:

When we need to set a null value, we have to set it to `undefined`, which is contrary to the semantics.(eg: dispatch(SetUser(undefined)))

```js
// store
const initState = {
  user?: User
}

// Child component
type ComponentProps = {
  user?: User
}
const Component: FC<ComponentProps> = ...

// Parent component
const {user} = store
<Component user={user}>

// Update state when we need nil value
setUser(undefined)

// Api call
api.getSomething({ user: store.user })
```

Comment: By reading [this](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state) seems that, when you combine reducers, the best approach is the `undefined` one. But I'm not a redux expert...